# How can I create a number of objects in R and store them in separate CSVs?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, model

I've been researching this question today, what i've found so far tells me how to loop over the existing CSVs in a directory and do things but i can't seem to find how to solve my specific issue

What I want to do is:

1) split my data frame into some portions

2) for each portion I want to write it as a CSV saving its name as data_i where "i" is the index of the loop

3) for each portion run a matching model from MatchIt

4) for each portion and matching model get the matched data

5) save the matched data as an object called matched_data_i.csv again "i" is the loop index

6) finish the loop by removing the data_i and the matching model

here is some code that doesn't work but shows where I want to be:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MatchIt)

data("mtcars")
View(mtcars)

n <- 10
nr <- nrow(mtcars)

splitter <- split(mtcars, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr))

for(i in splitter){
  write.csv(splitter[i], file = paste0(data_i)) ## this is a part I need help on, how do i name each CSV according to its loop index?

  ### how do i name each object  mod_match_[i] where i is the index of the loop?

  mod_match_[i] = matchit(am ~ mpg + wt, method = "nearest", data = as.data.frame(splitter[i])) ##I think it is a data frame anyway but doesn't hurt to be sure since matchit falls over when exposed to tibbles (from experience)

  matched_data_[i] = match.data(mod_match_[i]) ### again i don't know how to make the name of this object change depending on which "i" we're up to

  write.csv(matched_data_[i], file = "matched_data_[i].csv") ## how can i save each one as a separate CSV with a name referring to the index?

  ## i want to remove the objects before repeating the loop

  rm(mod_match_[i])
  rm(matched_data_[i])

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider encapsulating your process in a defined function and use function objects without the need of naming or removing from environment. Also, use `paste` (or its non-space wrapper, `paste0`) on the very column used for splitting. Below includes two alternative, equivalent solutions:

**Function**

```
proc_match <- function(sub) {

   write.csv(sub, file = paste0("data_", sub$nr[[1]], ".csv"))

   match_result <- matchit(am ~ mpg + wt, method = "nearest", data = sub) 
   matched_data <- match.data(match_result) 

   write.csv(matched_data, file = paste0("matched_data_", sub$nr[[1]], ".csv"))
}
```

**`split` + `lapply`**

```
# ADD NEW GROUPING COLUMN
mtcars$grp <- rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr)

# RUN PROCESS TO RETURN NOTHING
lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$grp), proc_match)
```

**`by`**

```
# ADD NEW GROUPING COLUMN
mtcars$grp <- rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr)

# RUN PROCESS TO RETURN NOTHING
by(mtcars, mtcars$grp, proc_match)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I actually need the solution to be able to drop each split of the data after i've saved it. That's why I tried to do it in a for loop

Comment: Then call `lapply(split(...))` and `by` without assigning to any object (i.e,. no list of splits created) and remove the `return` line. See edit.

Comment: This works reasonably well. Interesting that the matching model seems to fail o basically every subset of any dataset, but this code is good

Answer (score 0):

Huge thanks to Parfait for pointing me in the right direction especially with the paste0s. What I really struggled with is that split() seems to rename the columns of each DF in the list which broke the code (made it return NULL).

This is another solution which more closely matches what I need the code to do in the wild (i.e. not on a small dataset like lalonde). Hopefully it is of use to someone in future.

```
## packages
library(tidyverse)
library(MatchIt)

##data
data("lalonde")

## randomize the data because lalonde is sorted by treated so the mathcing will fail for some subsets
lalonde2 <- lalonde[sample(nrow(lalonde)),]

##set the size of each subset
n <- 30
nr <- nrow(lalonde2)

### make the subsets
splitter <- split(lalonde2, rep(1:ceiling(nr/n), each=n, length.out=nr))

## write them to file (with replaced names because split() changed them)
for(i in 1:length(splitter)){
  names(splitter[[i]]) <- c("treat", "age", "educ", "black", "hispan", "married", "nodegree", "re74", "re75", "re78")
  write.csv(splitter[[i]], file = paste0("data_", i, ".csv")) 
}

## remove the big one 
rm(splitter)

## for loop that runs through each of the saved files from earlier, runs a matching model and matches the data and writes it to a file all in one

require(stringr)
for (i in 1:ceiling(nr/n)){
  file<- read.csv(str_c("data_",i,".csv"))
  write.csv(match.data(matchit(treat ~ age + educ, method = "nearest", data = file, ratio = 1)), file = paste0("matched_data_", i, ".csv"))
  ### remove the data after each iteration
  rm(file)

}
```